# How to export iMessages from OS X app onto new iPhone?

Tags: messages

Just got a new iphone 5s and I'd like to export the messages from the 'Messages' OS X app on my computer to the iPhone's messages app.  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Not possible, sorry to crush your hopes.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible on a non-jailbroken iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Your [messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/59503/46541) are saved on Mavericks in the

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages
```

You can saved them as text file (email) to your iPhone but not as individual messages that would work with iPhone message app. This way you would at least have the history if you need to look up.